# Creating DOM element - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild')

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Im trying to dynamically append a div element into HTML DOM from JS script, like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Result</title>

    <style>
        .chart-container {
            position: relative;
            height: 40vh;
            width: 80vw;
        }
    </style>

    <script defer>
        var divContainer = document.createElement('div');
        divContainer.className = 'chart-container';
        document.body.appendChild(divContainer);

        ... REST OF THE SCRIPT
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Metrics Information:</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

But for some reason this results only in:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `defer` attribute on a `<script>` tag has no effect for inline scripts. It only works for scripts imported via a `src` attribute. Thus, at the point your script runs, the `<body>` hasn't been seen.

If you move your script to the end of the `<body>` section, it should work (well, the posted 3 lines should work).

Comment: Ah! That was it indeed - thanks :) (will accept the answer in 7 minutes)